# WP / Rev Slider / particles.js

Tags: javascript, wordpress, revolution-slider

we are using the Revolution Slider and wordpress, both in newest versions.
Actually we want to set this : http://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/
as a background animation.
We used the code snippet you get when you hit code pen in the upper right corner.
The html part was added as a layer.
css and js part were added to the custom css / custom javascript field in the slider settings.

The problem:
When the page starts nothing happens. No animation appears. If I hit the area with a right click and press q (in firefox) the animation starts to work.

So I guess it is about a loading issue!?

Can anyone imagine a solution with the given base?

Regards,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Do you check your console? How have you integrated the script? After testing, it works for me. The piece of javascript must be placed at the end of the page, or create a function wich starts when page is loaded.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! To implement the javascript we just pasted the code to the custom javascript field of the slider. I will try to put the javascript as a file to assets/js folder.

Comment: you can also try to wrap javascript in an onload handler : `window.onload=function(){particlesJS...};`

Comment: This worked scraaappy :-D Thank you very much!!! You saved my day! is there a way to rate your answer / help?